# Angular: What makes this getter(s) different from a public member?

Tags: angular

I'm developing an angular application where I have a diagram with several different modules. Each module has a module-type which is an enum of type `ModuleType`. When I click a module I want to display it's module-type via reverse-mapping [as seen here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings).

The event handler looks like this:

```
handleModuleFocusChanged(args: ModuleSettingsEventArgs) {
  if (args.visible) {
    this.currentModuleType = args.module.type;
  } else {
    this.currentModuleType = ModuleType.Undefined;
  }

  console.log('currentmoduletype = ' + this.currentModuleType + ' (' + ModuleType[this.currentModuleType] + ')');
}
```

Now I tried different implementations for `Module`, which are equal in my eyes (except for data encapsulation of course), but only one of them works. To test it I *only* changed the implementation of `Module` to one of the three below, recompiled and reloaded the page. So everything else is the same in all three tests.

**1. With public member:**
leads to correct output: `currentmoduletype = 1 (Create)`

```
export abstract class Module {
  constructor(type: ModuleType) {
      this.type = type;
  }

  public type: ModuleType;
}
```

**2. With getter and private member:**
leads to wrong output: `currentmoduletype = undefined (undefined)`

```
export abstract class Module {
  private fType: ModuleType;

  constructor(type: ModuleType) {
      this.fType = type;
  }

  public get type(): ModuleType {
      return this.fType;
  }
}
```

**3. Shorthand version of the former:**
leads to wrong output: `currentmoduletype = undefined (undefined)`

```
export abstract class Module {
  constructor(private fType: ModuleType) {
  }

  public get type(): ModuleType {
      return this.fType;
  }
}
```

I'm totally confused why only one of the three works. What do I miss here?

---

This sounds like it could be duplicate, but I did some research and found nothing that would explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Module object is not initialized with `new`, thus the methods are not defined. You can access fields, because they are (not sure if that is proper word) dynamically casted. In other words, as I do not know much about your example and who is calling the `handleModuleFocusChanged(args: ModuleSettingsEventArgs)` lets assume we have a http method like:

```
public getModules(): Observable<Module> {
    return this.http.get<Module>(SOME_URL);
  }
```

this will lead to your case, object ModuleType is not created, just dynamically casted, but when you call it like:

```
public getModules(): Observable<Module> {
    return this.http.get<Module>(SOME_URL)
         .map(module => new Module(module));
  }
```

and 
the `Module` should like like:

```
export abstract class Module {
  constructor(module) {
      this.type = module ? module.type : null;
  }

  // any method you wish
}
```

Comment: Actually I use new to create the instances. But the basic idea is good and I will do some more research on this. Maybe the third party framework is messing with my objects.